# expect interpreter with sshfs

Tags: linux, bash, expect, sshfs

cant manage to work this out

```
!/usr/bin/expect -f
set prompt ":|#|\\\$"
set HOST "192.168.0.40"
set USER "root"
set PASS "1234"
set PATH "/rpms"
spawn "sshfs" "$USER@$HOST:$PATH" "/backup"
expect "Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)?"
send "yes\r"
expect "root@192.168.0.40's password:"
send "PASS\r"
exit
```

output I'm getting:

```
spawn sshfs root@192.168.0.40:/rpms /backup
root@192.168.0.40's password: root@debian:/rpms#
```

and directory is not mounting:

```
cd /backup
-bash: cd: /backup: Transport endpoint is not connected
```

If I'll try manually `sshfs root@192.168.0.40:/rpms /backup`   it works just fine

Comment: Get rid of `expect "Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)?" send "yes\r"` portion..

Comment: It seems it works without too, but still getting : #cd /backup
> -bash: cd: /backup: Transport endpoint is not connected

Comment: When you do `sshfs root@192.168.0.40:/rpms /backup`, does it ask for password?

Comment: manually yes, and when providing it, mounts ok, looking at output, it asks too..

Comment: Here: `send "$PASS\r"`

Comment: still the same ....    /rpms# ls /backup
ls: cannot access /backup: Transport endpoint is not connected

Answer (score 0):

You are saving the password as variable `PASS`, but sending the string `PASS` as the password; pass the variable expansion:

```
send "$PASS\r"
```

Comment: you are right, strange is that sending string PASS I'm not getting any error..,  changed to "$PASS\r" but the result is still the same...  remote directory is not mounted:  ls /backup lls: cannot access /backup: Transport endpoint is not connected

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem -- `sshfs` appears to work from everywhere else, but not from inside `expect`. Why could this be?
is `expect` terminating it early or what?

my code for `expect`:

```bash
spawn bash -c "sshfs  user@host.local:/ /home/user/remote-fs  -o ssh_command='ssh -o HostKeyAlgorithms=+ssh-rsa -o PubkeyAcceptedKeyTypes=+ssh-rsa'"
```

This command works perfectly fine from bash, but fails silently with "transport endpoint not connected" when used from `expect`